# mysql insert trigger only if not duplicate

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am little bit confused with the usage of trigger event to get expected result

Here main table is `fee`. The structure is as follow

**Fee**

```
id  |   rn  |   fid |   amount  |   f_month |   year
====================================================
1   |   1   |   1   |   150000  |   1       |   1
2   |   1   |   2   |   50000   |   1       |   1
3   |   2   |   1   |   550500  |   2       |   1
4   |   2   |   2   |   200     |   2       |   1
5   |   3   |   1   |   550500  |   2       |   1
```

And the simply insert trigger has been used.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `insertinv`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `insertinv`
AFTER INSERT ON `fee` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO invoice VALUES(null, NEW.rn, NEW.year, '')
```

The output what I am getting

**Invoice**

```
inv |   rn  |   y_d |   status  
==============================
1   |   1   |   1   |   0
2   |   1   |   1   |   0
3   |   2   |   1   |   0
4   |   2   |   1   |   0
5   |   3   |   1   |   0
```

But I want to apply condition

if `fee.rn` AND `fee.f_month` AND `fee.year` is same then **stop to insert**. I mean ignore the `fee.fid`.

and achieve following result. The expected one

**Invoice**

```
inv |   rn  |   y_d |   status  
==============================
1   |   1   |   1   |   0
2   |   2   |   1   |   0
3   |   3   |   1   |   0
```

In trigger table `inv` is primary key and auto increment

Comment: You trigger syntax does not look alright. Have you given a pseudocode only ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, I've edited, It is that what you mean, isn't it ?

Comment: No, write you complete trigger statement in the question. is your current trigger doing something or not ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, current trigger is working, I've posted result - first **invoice table**, but what I am expected as last **invoice table**

Comment: Please add the **complete** current trigger statement to your question. I will edit that trigger itself

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: You are not storing month in your invoices table. Am assuming that only year and rn can be matched.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this you seem to be happy to allow a duplicate entry into fee but not into invoice?

Comment: @AnandHmt please check the answer. Since you dont have month in the invoice table, I cant consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check if a `inv` exists for a matching `year` and `rn`.
- If it does not exist, then use the `insert` statement.

Do the following:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `insertinv` $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `insertinv`
AFTER INSERT ON `fee` 
FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN

    /* Declare a variable to store invoice id for matching year and rn */
    DECLARE inv_exists INT(11) DEFAULT 0;

    /* Fetch the invoice id if exists */
    SELECT inv INTO inv_exists 
    FROM invoice 
    WHERE rn = NEW.rn AND 
          y_d = NEW.year; 

    /* if no invoice exists then insert into the table */
    IF NOT(inv_exists > 0) THEN 

        /* Insert statement */
        INSERT INTO invoice VALUES(null, NEW.rn, NEW.year, '') ;

    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: your answer not only solved my problem but also realized my structure was wrong and I found my table structure has to be revised. Huge !!! Respect to you man for your guidelines also. Please edit the typo mistake in answer `semicolon` is missing before the `END IF`. Once again thanks.

Comment: @AnandHmt happy to help :)